# Objective C calculator counting priority

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, calculator

I have done a simple Objective C calculator in Xcode. It works perfectly except of one thing. For example when I count 4+5*2 the calculator shows the answer "18". It should be "14". It starts with 4+5 and then multiply it with 2. I want it to multiply 5 with 2 and then add 4.

I have been searching for an answer to my question without any results.

Here is the code of my calculator:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
-(IBAction) zeroButton;
-(IBAction) oneButton;
-(IBAction) twoButton;
-(IBAction) threeButton;
-(IBAction) fourButton;
-(IBAction) fiveButton;
-(IBAction) sixButton;
-(IBAction) sevenButton;
-(IBAction) eightButton;
-(IBAction) nineButton;
-(IBAction) divideButton;
-(IBAction) multiButton;
-(IBAction) plusButton;
-(IBAction) minusButton;
-(IBAction) resultButton;
-(IBAction) resetButton;
-(IBAction) decimalButton;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize display;
char myOperator;
NSString *operatorNumber;
bool numberClear = false;

-(void) clearNumber{
    if (numberClear) {
        display.text = @"";
        numberClear = false;
    }}

-(IBAction) zeroButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    if ([display.text isEqual:@"0"]){
     display.text=@"0";
    }
    else{
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0",display.text];}
}

-(IBAction) oneButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@1",display.text];}

-(IBAction) twoButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@2",display.text];}

-(IBAction) threeButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@3",display.text];}

-(IBAction) fourButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@4",display.text];}

-(IBAction) fiveButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@5",display.text];}

-(IBAction) sixButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@6",display.text];}

-(IBAction) sevenButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@7",display.text];}

-(IBAction) eightButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@8",display.text];}

-(IBAction) nineButton {
    [self clearNumber];
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@9",display.text];}

-(IBAction) decimalButton {
    [self clearNumber];
NSRange decimal = [display.text rangeOfString:@"."];
if ( decimal.location == NSNotFound ) {
    display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",display.text];}
}



-(IBAction) resetButton {
    display.text = @"";
    operatorNumber=@"";
    myOperator=0;
}

-(void)operatorCalculation{

    if (myOperator != 0) {
        [self calculateNewNumber];
        numberClear = true;
    } else {
        operatorNumber = display.text;
        display.text = @"";
    }
}

-(IBAction) plusButton {
    [self operatorCalculation];
    myOperator='+';
}


-(IBAction) minusButton {
    [self operatorCalculation];
    myOperator='-';
}

-(IBAction) multiButton {
    [self operatorCalculation];
    myOperator='*';
}

-(IBAction) divideButton {
    [self operatorCalculation];
    myOperator='/';
}

-(IBAction) resultButton {
    [self operatorCalculation];
    myOperator='=';
}


- (void)calculateNewNumber {
    switch (myOperator) {
        case '+': {
            NSString *secondNumber = display.text;
            float number1 = [operatorNumber floatValue];
            float number2 = [secondNumber floatValue];
            operatorNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", number1+number2];
            display.text = operatorNumber;
            break;
        }
        case '-': {
            NSString *secondNumber = display.text;
            float number1 = [operatorNumber floatValue];
            float number2 = [secondNumber floatValue];
            operatorNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", number1-number2];
            display.text = operatorNumber;
            break;
        }
        case '*': {
            NSString *secondNumber = display.text;
            float number1 = [operatorNumber floatValue];
            float number2 = [secondNumber floatValue];
            operatorNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", number1*number2];
            display.text = operatorNumber;
            break;
        }
        case '/': {
            NSString *secondNumber = display.text;
            float number1 = [operatorNumber floatValue];
            float number2 = [secondNumber floatValue];
            if (number2==0) {
                display.text=@"0";
            }
            else{
            operatorNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", number1/number2];
                display.text = operatorNumber;}
            break;
        }
        case '=': {
            operatorNumber = display.text;
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating your answer as the user enters their equation. If you want to support operator precedence (eg: multiplication and division having high priority that addition and subtraction), you are going to have to store the results and not display until finished. Also, you are going to have to implement your own calculation engine for making these precedence decisions. It's not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I am going back into my memory banks but from what I recall you need to wait for an operation to be complete before reading more data (numeric values). This can be achieved with a simple flag. Obviously if you extend the functionality to include things like brackets the logic will have to be extended.